# Bootstrap - Columns not align on same row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I have a Bootstrap row with 2 columns. But when viewing it in the browser's phone emulation, it displays as two rows. In regular dekstop modus, it does render as expected.

Any idea what is causing this?

[image]

```
<header role="heading" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">                  
                    def
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 ">
                    abc                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: use class="col-xs-2" and class="col-xs-9" for extra small screen.

Comment: Holy can't believe I missed that. Thanks @AtulKumar. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Atul Kumar said, "sm" is incorrect and it should be "xs"